# Iam hitting api with postman iam getting response when i use curl i got null response

Tags: php, opencart, payment

this is my code block.I get null for that hit via curl while postman gives the positive response and get all the required data specified in documentation. Iam using a payment gateway iam also providing the link of documentation https://docs.ngenius-payments.com/reference#request-an-access-token-paypage

```
$apikey = "My api key";     // enter your API key here
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        // var_dump($ch);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://identity-uat.ngeniuspayments.com/auth/realms/ni/protocol/openidconnect/token"); 
         $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($headers);
         echo "</pre>";
        $test = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Basic'.$apikey, 
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

            // var_dump($test);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query(array(grant_type => client_credentials))); 
        var_dump($ch);
        $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        $access_token = $output->access_token;

        print_r($access_token);
```

Comment: Did you get any error message from [curl_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) with [curl_strerror](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-strerror.php)?

Comment: Might be something as simple as a missing space after "Basic". I would prefer use of CURLOPT_USERPWD. Anyway, to debug it I would first try curl on command line. One less layer to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems in past and best way is to contact payment gateway technicals and ask for your logs , as in my case code was 100% fine but I got rejected every time coz of my server's settings and SSL and TLS versions.

payment gateway has very strict requirements (about ssl/tls)

Comment: right said i contacted them. The support provided me the solution.

Comment: glad to hear :)